# How to generate multiple records for every record in a table using a column value in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops, iteration

Consider the following scenario:

```
Area    Code    Count
BP      90-99    10
CL      78-87    10
```

I need ten records generated for both of these.

```
Area    Code
BP      90
BP      91
BP      92
BP      93
BP      94
BP      95
BP      96
BP      97
BP      98 and so on.
```

In oracle, this can be easily done by using connect by level. How to do this using MySQL. Please note that I do have the number of iterations to be made in the third column called count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a table of numbers.  This can be generated as a derived table on-the-fly:

```
select area,
       (substring_index(code, '-', 1) + n.n - 1) as code
from (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7 union all
      select 8 union all select 9 union all select 10
     ) n join
     scenario s
     on n.n <= s.count;
```

You need to be sure that the list of numbers is big enough for the maximum count in the tables.  It is handy if you have a table of numbers available.  Normally, an `auto_increment` column can help generate such a table.

Comment: It is a very elegant solution that you have provided. I have got a lot to learn about MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use number table and try this approach

```
Create table numbers(number int)
insert into numbers(number)
select 1 union all
select 2 union all
.
.
.
select 100

select t1.area, left(code,locate('-',code)-1)*1 from table as t1
inner join numbers as t2 on 1=1
where left(code,locate('-',code)-1)*1 +number 
<=substring(code,locate('-',code)+1,length(code))*1
```

Comment: Check the above solution. It is beautiful.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an idea, you can simply use this code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tab (area nchar(2), code nvarchar(10), count int)

INSERT INTO #tab(area, code, count)
VALUES(N'BP',N'90-99', 10),(N'CL',N'78-87',10)

SELECT *
FROM #tab t
OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT TOP(t.count) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY object_id) + CONVERT(int,SUBSTRING(t.code,1,PATINDEX(N'%-%',t.code)-1)) as nr 
        FROM sys.all_objects 
    ) as oa

DROP TABLE #tab
```

In this case I'm using `sys.all_objects` just to get a table to number everything. You can use every other table you have. Even `#tab` itself, if it's big enough to have enough rows. Another solution is to use a `CTE` Expression to generate those needed rows. :-)

Comment: The question is tagged "mysql" and this syntax is not supported by MySQL.

Comment: Ah okay. Haven't seen it. I've watched the SQL-Server tags. Maybe the tag was removed/changed afterwards? Anyway, I leave it if someone needs this later on for his own problem.

Comment: @Ionic - No worries pal. Will check this for SQL Server also.